# Apple watch CoreMotion on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-motion, watchos-3

It's possible to get the `CoreMotion` data from the Apple watch directly on the iPhone without using `WatchConnectivity`?

The thing is that now, I'm getting Apple watch accelerometer on the `WatchKit Extension` and transferring it to the iPhone via `WatchConnectivity`, but I want to record this accelerometer directly from the iPhone because `WatchConnectivity` fails in some cases.

Anyone knows how to do this? Thank you very much in any case!

Answer (score 0):

1. NSURL Session on Apple Watch would be another choice
2. However I think WatchConnectivity should sufficiently support your use case. Could you please elaborate on in what cases WatchConnectivity fails for you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Finally, I solved myself this issue. The problem was the payload, too long.
Thanks again!!

Comment: @ainovela hi, how you solve this issue, sorry I didn't get you well from your previous comment, thanks